# Can I Cache/Save Expensive SQL Queries for a week?

Tags: python, sql

I have a very large DB with 50 million records. I
I have some very expensive queries that I want to run for indepth statistics purposes. These queries will slow down the server/database. So i dont want to run them more than once - I want to run them on a sunday night and store the results for the week.

I dont want to index the data on ALL the relevant fields as it would take a long time, and would need to be re-done a lot since i blow away the DB every few weeks.

Is there any software/tools/practices that will save the results of expensive queries for an indefinitve amount of time. 
My currnet method of thinking is to do the queries once and write the results to a new table in the database called "stats".
Im using python.

Comment: Maybe add the concrete database you combine in your processing together with python, so specific solutions may be offered more easily? Also the python code you have already could be helpful. Would that database or table be in the same DB "product" or would you also think about say adding sqlite to the mix (a third component for caching). What about memcached which is quite often used in my experience in more web centric layered apps, that want some queries to  not hit the DB too often. Did you already ensure, that your expensive SQL queries are optimized, as that could reduce the problem?

Comment: Yes, the queries are optimized. Sqlite sounds good - might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [job agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) that comes with [SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) for similar purposes. If your DB is not SQL Server you can add it as a [linked server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) in the management studio and run the query via [openquery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) command. You can set detailed schedules, email/sms alerts etc. with your job.

To save output to disk you could use a command similar to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7d2280cf-3b33-46f7-ba82-4131e8a841c0/how-to-export-data-to-csv-file-on-a-scheduled-basis?forum=transactsql) in your job step:

EXEC  master.xp_cmdshell 'SQLCMD -S server\SQLSERVERDEV2005 -E -Q "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM pubs.dbo.authors" -b -o c:\myoutput.txt', no_output